# Azure AD password reset error - calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<username>' returns Status 400 Bad Request

Tags: active-directory, password

Our AD management code was working for more than 12 months between mid 2018 and mid 2019. Suddenly, with no code change at our side, it stopped working for password reset.

The last line of code returns error. I wonder if there are any breaking changes in Azure AD - which are still undocumented. Does anyone has similar issues?

URL used in Visual Studio: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/

Response:

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: private
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  request-id: 0e480608-1ec5-4286-abb2-ecf7406f6788
  client-request-id: 0e480608-1ec5-4286-abb2-ecf7406f6788
  x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Australia Southeast","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_0","ADSiteName":"ASE"}}
  Duration: 159.8111
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  Date: Tue, 09 Jul 2019 03:45:57 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json
}}

Code:
var authHeader = await getAuthenticationHeader();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader))
{
  logger.LogInformation("Auth header is null, reset password failed");
  return false;
}

_logger.LogInformation("Getting user by user principal");
var exists = await GetUserByUserPrincipal(user.Email);
if (exists == null)
{
  _logger.LogInformation("User returned as null");
  return false;
}

var graphUrl = Uri.EscapeUriString(string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/{0}/users/{1}", _configuration.ApiVersion, exists.userPrincipalName)).Replace("#", "%23");

// make sure that this isn't here
exists.passwordProfile = new MSGraphAPIPasswordProfile
            {
                forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
                password = user.Password
            };

var body = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exists, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader);

// because this is a patch call we need to build the request object differently
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = new HttpMethod("PATCH"),
                RequestUri = new Uri(graphUrl),
                Content = body,
            };

_logger.LogInformation("Resetting user password");

// the response returns Status 400 error.

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the URL for the current signed-in user the URL is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me, might have changed from having to pass the user id.

Answer (score 0):

Today Azure AD fixed the issue. I was told that using 'users?filter={username}' query string in the url is an alternative.